# Tableau percentage increase toggle for multiple columns

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 fields: |CNTD(OrderID)|Charged Amount|Paid Amount|

I would just like to create a toggle where the end user can just input a percentage number to show percent increase accross the board for those fields. I will clone the existing fields as new columns.

I would like my result to like this:

% Increase Input: `10`%

> |CNTD(OrderID)|Charged Amount|Paid Amount||CNTD(OrderID)|ChargedAmt|Paid Amt|
>
> ```
> 100           $10000        $1000        110          $11000     $1100
> ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

1) Create Parameter: Percent Increase
  - Data type: Float
  - Current value: 1
  - Diplay format: Automatic

2) For each field create a calculated field and tie it back to the parameter with this formula:
((COUNTD([OrderId])*[Percent Increase])/100)+COUNTD([OrderId])

Dividing by 100 will let you just enter a whole number for the percent instead of needing to move the decimal over.  For the rest of the fields Just plug the field names into where the (COUNTD([OrderId]) from above shows up.